# How to check if track bar value increased or decreased in vb.net 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a track bar in vb.net 2015,I need to know if it's value has been decreased or in increased on scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a variable which keeps track of the last value, then compare in the `Scroll` event, and update the variable to the new value

```vb
Private lastValue As Integer

Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
    Dim change = TrackBar1.Value - lastValue
    If change > 0 Then ' increasing

    ElseIf change < 0 ' decreasing

    Else ' stayed the same
    
    End If
    lastValue = TrackBar1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you i used this code and it solved my problem.

Comment: @WajdiSaeed Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You could add a handler on the [TrackBar.ValueChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.trackbar.valuechanged?view=netframework-4.8). This may be sufficient for your needs if you don't care about the previous value. The difference with the Scroll event:

> Occurs when the Value property of a track bar changes, either by
> movement of the scroll box or by manipulation in code.

Comment: OP specifically said `Scroll` however you're right that this captures any change. But how will you know `"if it's value has been decreased or in increased [sic]"`?